# calling webservice with Arabic message

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, oracle-apps

If I request an English message it return `200 Ok`. But 
every time I request an Arabic SOAP message the response is

```
Unexpected end of input block in end tag at [row,col {unknown-source}]
```

I'm using encoding utf-8 and it worked before now it does not. I don't know whether my data base is al16utf16.  Please help me.

Example for my XML request:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <typ:createLocation>
     <typ:location>
        <loc:LocationId></loc:LocationId>
        <loc:SetCode>COMMON</loc:SetCode>
        <loc:ActiveStatus>A</loc:ActiveStatus>
        <loc:ShipToSiteFlag>true</loc:ShipToSiteFlag>
        <loc:ShipToLocationSetCode>COMMON</loc:ShipToLocationSetCode>
        <loc:ShipToLocationCode>L99999</loc:ShipToLocationCode>
        <loc:ShipToLocationId></loc:ShipToLocationId>
        <loc:ReceivingSiteFlag>true</loc:ReceivingSiteFlag>
        <loc:BillToSiteFlag>true</loc:BillToSiteFlag>
        <loc:OfficeSiteFlag>true</loc:OfficeSiteFlag>
        <loc:LocationCode>'||r.location_code||'</loc:LocationCode>
        <loc:LocationName>'||r.location_code||'</loc:LocationName>
        <loc:Description>'||r.Description||'</loc:Description>
        <loc:Country>'||r.country||'</loc:Country>
        <loc:AddressLine1>'||R.ADDRESS_LINE_1||'</loc:AddressLine1>
        <loc:AddressLine2>'||R.ADDRESS_LINE_2||'</loc:AddressLine2>
        <loc:AddressLine3>'||R.ADDRESS_LINE_3||'</loc:AddressLine3>
        <loc:TownOrCity>'||r.town_or_city||'</loc:TownOrCity>
        <loc:RangeStartDate>1950-01-01</loc:RangeStartDate>
        <loc:RangeEndDate></loc:RangeEndDate>
        <loc:SourceSystemOwner></loc:SourceSystemOwner>
        <loc:SourceSystemId></loc:SourceSystemId>
     </typ:location>
  </typ:createLocation>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

I'm using this message in EBS to send data to Oracle Fusion application.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us at least one example that works, and at least one example that fails. Maybe the remote end does not cope with UTF-8 well. If "it worked before", then you changed something that broke it, or the remote end changed something that broke it.

Comment: when i send the request from ebs and it contains english words it works if it arabic words it returns with Unexpected end of input block in end tag
 at [row,col {unknown-source}] , i dont know my data base is al16utf16 what shall i do

Comment: Again, [edit] your post. Show us the example XML that works. Show us the example XML that fails. We don't know what your data looks like, and we don't know what your webservice looks like. Check that your XML matches the WSDL in both cases.

Comment: this is and example for my xml request if any  of the data takes an arabic word it returns with the error if it is english it returns 200 ok

Comment: im using this message in ebs to send data to oracle fusion application